# How to run windows command without window in JavaScript using nsIProcess

Tags: javascript, firefox, command-line, firefox-addon

I'd like to run some command for example:

```
notepad C:\file.txt
```

using Firefox addon and [nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess). I've already written code like bellow:

```
var exepath = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
var args = ["/c", "notepad", "C:\file.txt"];
var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath(exepath);
var process = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);
process.run(true, args, args.length);
```

But I don't want opening window. **Is it possible to run some command without opening this window?**

I know, that I can use `cmd.exe /C start notepad` to close this window after command executed, but it flashes (appears and disappears). Additionally I'd like to read exit value:

```
var exitval = process.exitValue;
```

I forgot to mention that I can't install any additional software!

Comment: Please don't suggest edits if you don't have anything to improve. Hint: applying boldface font to random parts of the post is not an improvement.

Comment: I wanted to highlight these places which I think are important and I missed reading first time. In my opinion if something is i.e bolded, people focused on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Notepad directly - you don't need `cmd.exe` for that. But you have to find the full path of the executable. Its path is `%windir%/notepad.exe`, you can use [nsIEnvironment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIEnvironment) to resolve that path (something you actually have to do with `cmd.exe` as well instead of assuming that Windows is installed in `c:\windows`):

```
var env = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIEnvironment);
var exepath = env.get("WINDIR") + "\\notepad.exe";
```

And just in case you want to run something other than Notepad: you will have to do the work that the command line is normally doing, namely getting the `PATH` environment variable and going through the directories in the list, looking where the file exits.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a old question but this page is well ranked on google results**

To avoid windows appears and disappears you shold use this command

[system/child_process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is [better to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: While it may be helpful to have an answer that is Firefox Add-on SDK based attached to this question, the question is clearly *not* about the Add-on SDK. Given that, you should at least mention in your answer that it is for those using the Add-on SDK.